# Subdomains using UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, subdomain, angular-ui-router

I am using UI-Router in my Angularjs app on Apache. I want to use subdomains for user profiles. How can I change  http://example.com/variable to http://variable.example.com and trailing urls.
Is there a way this could be done using htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when a user logs in your server side code should redirect them to their subdomain with an HTTP 302 redirect. Once there, the angular app can load. Note that changing the hostname will cause a full page reload (your angular app will start over), so you could do this for login but you wouldn't want to do this if userA is allowed to visit userB's profile as angularjs is optimized for single page applications and using subdomains like this would make your app a multi-page application.

Comment: So I have to do this using server side. I don't mind reloading the page. What I wanted to ask is if there is a way htaccess could solve this. But from your answer I will call it no.

Comment: Sorry I don't know enough about apache/.htaccess to say.